# Stop Over for JR ticket holder

Tags: trains, public-transport, tickets, japan, japan-rail

I am traveling from Sapporo to Hakodate and will make a stop over at Okumakoen station. I understand that I can make stop over with the same ticket same day. But if I would like to reserve the seat for Sapporo-Okumakoen and Okumakoen- Hakodate sections, how do I do it? Separately ? Or at once when purchase ticket at the JR counter?

Comment: Do you have a JR pass ?

Comment: Is the station you are mentioning called Okuma-Koen? Google only returns results for Onuma-Koen, with an N.

Comment: Short answer: Yes, the seat reservations must be made separately, so you will get two separate reserved seat tickets in addition to a single base fare ticket. Since Sapporo to Hakodate is 319 kilometers, your base fare ticket will be valid for three days.

Comment: @fkraiem This is not a duplicate. This question asks specifically about seat reservations, an issue that the other question and its answer don't seem to cover at all.

Comment: Is Onumakoen, typo error, and thanks for the reply, i got the answer !

Comment: I am still considering buying Hokkaido Flexi 4 days or single trip ticket. Can anyone give an idea which one is more cost saving? I need to travel within Hokkaido by train during end of November for 5 sections as below: 1. New Chitose Airport to Saporro-Day 1 2. Sapporo- Otaru(return)-Day 2( may use Welcome Pass) Day 1,2 &3 stay at Sapporo 3. Sapporo – Hakodate( single trip)-Day 4 Day 4 & 5, stay at Hakodate 4. Hakodate -Noboribetsu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its possible to reserve separately or together.

Which is the best course of action depends on how planned you are.

If you know how much time you wish to stay between trains, you can reserve both trains at the same ticketing office and be sure you have your places ready.

If you are unsure how long, then you should reserve the second leg on the spot when you are ready to leave.

Keep in mind that outside the busy holidays (golden week, obon, etc) there is *usually* no need to reserve seats as the trains are not full. Note that this might not apply to the line you are taking, verify its popularity before taking a decision.

Comment: Some trains require reservation, probably unlikely in Hokkaido though

Comment: Really? Ive never seen one...

Comment: Yeah, I can't remember if I needed that in Hokkaido, but in Honshu for sure, some shinkansen are reservation only http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2016.html

Comment: @JSLavertu The Tohoku Shinkansen Hayabusa or Hayate services for example.

Comment: -1 Does not answer the question. The question is whether the reservations must be made separately, not when is the best time to make them.

Comment: Except it is *not possible* to make a single reservation. So this answer went from "does not answer the question" to "incorrect".

Comment: Except its possible. I did so last time I went to Japan.

Comment: Pleas keep comments civil guys, and take conversations to a [chat].